# Forces and magnetic lines of force

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, vectors

Magnet releases the magnetic lines of force which can attract magnetic substance. Can all the non-contact forces (such as gravitation, electrostatic, etc) release these so called lines of forces? If yes, then what are these lines? Do they have physical existence? When someone say it releases lines, then what do they mean to say?

And one thing also , can you please explain me it with the help of "particle physics"?

**Note: please don't use high level of Physics as I am in 12th grade**

Comment: Given you don't want a high level of Physics, what exactly do you mean when you ask for an answer involving Particle Physics? Notice that Particle Physics is something quite complicated

Comment: Mr. Nickolas , you can explain at whatever level do you want

Answer (score 0):

Lines of forces are applicable to electric field , magnetic field , gravitational field (notice the word "field"). They do not have any physical significance means nothing mathematical. But it does have *logical* meaning and is only a way of representation. **LIKE** in physics if we see those field lines concentrated at a point or some area it means that there value at that point or area is high compared to other areas, and if they are parallel they mean that they are uniform (value of that field is same). This concept is also extended to fluid mechanics to express streamline flow etc etc.

look in you textbook : electric field lines emerging from a point charge you will feel and understand it better. near the point charge the lines are very close and hence electric field is very high ... you can confirm it mathematically too
Electric field is inversely proportional to distance squared.

Hope this helps you and even I am from 12th grade :)

sorry i dont know particle physics yet but i am sure it will same there too

Answer (score 0):

It is only representation, magnetic field is continuous. It represent the field, same as two axes represent a surface. One line show the one value of magnetic field.
A good analogy is the levelling represented on maps. Each lines represent a certain altitude, each 100m for example.

It can be confusing because if you google your question, you can see pictures of magnet with "lines" formed by iron powder. But it's only because iron become magnetised and become a small magnet itself, so it form filaments and align itself according to the magnet position.

Magnetic field, like all fields, can be represented in other ways than lines, for example small vectors at different points.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field is a vector field, which means it assumes a vectorial value at each point of spacetime. In order to get a better grasp of what the vector field looks like, we use visual aids, the force lines being one of them.

Pick a point. The magnetic field at that point is pointing somewhere. Follow this vector, and just keep following along whatever direction the magnetic field is pointing as you go moving. Doing this, you are drawing a field line. It is everywhere tangent to the vector field. In addition, we'll often draw more field lines in regions where the field is stronger. Notice that, since the field is everywhere, there are infinitely many field lines, but we can't draw them all, so we've got to choose which ones we want to keep when drawing a diagram.

Since they are a way of visualizing the vector field structure of the magnetic field, they do have physical significance. See, e.g., the discussion on the relevant [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_line), which partially inspires this answer. Of course, as mentioned in both Wikipedia and in another answer, the magnetic field is continuous and you shouldn't picture it as being a set of finitely many lines, but the lines can still be understood as a way of visualizing the physically meaningful field.

I am not sure about what you, or any other person, means when they say something "releases lines". The magnetic field exists independently of magnets or any other things, it merely interacts with matter. The lines are present throughout spacetime, they merely change when electric charges and currents (which make up magnets) move around.

Other fields can also be represented in terms of field lines. As mentioned in other answers, this is very common in fluid dynamics, in which one represents the fluid flow by streamlines. It is also very common to represent the electric field by field lines through the same ideas we use for the magnetic field. The same holds true for Newtonian gravity, but if we want to study really strong gravitational fields, we need to go to [General Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) and we can no longer describe the gravitational field as a vector field, and hence we can no longer picture it by means of field lines. Hence, some fields admit representations in terms of field lines, but it really depends on the details of the field.

As far as I know, there are no insights that Particle Physics would bring on this issue. Particle Physics also depends heavily on the field concept, but in a quantized setting, which changes the way we see things in a lot of manners. In particular, the concept of field lines is not very useful is these contexts.